# How to rotate or pan in the view port while performing scale or rotate actions

Tags: modeling

I am new to blender so im trying to check other angle when i tried to scale a face but i can only do that after conforming the action so is there a way to check the results of scale or rotation and even moving without applying it first .

Comment: The option will be available in version 4.0. From Release Notes: "It is now possible to navigate while transform (Move, Rotate, Scale, Edge Slide, Vert Slide, and Shrink/Fatten)" - https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/4.0/Modeling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can perform an operation in only one view, you could always pop in a quick split with a right-click on the frame of a region, and *view* it from different directions..

[image]

Comment: Thats great thanks